# ORA-SQL-PLSQL S41 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

We are migrating from Oracle 9i to Oracle 11gr2 and when i open a package in toad i am getting below error.

`(891:36) ORA-SQL-PLSQL S41
(S41) Expecting:    .    @   AS  CROSS  FULL  identifier  INNER  JOIN  LEFT  NATURAL  PARTITION  RIGHT  SAMPLE  SUBPARTITION  VERSIONS`

The package is getting complied when I try to compile it and it is also seems to be working fine.

Any idea why this error is happening? Will it cause any issue in production?

Note:
Cannot share the source due to copyright issues.

Comment: It only fails in Toad?  Is Toad setup to automatically format code when you open a package?  (If so, do the world a favor and disable that "feature"... it's infuriating when every line of code gets reformatted with every small change.)  Is there any unusual syntax in the code?

Comment: Check the version of the Oracle client your TOAD version is using.

Comment: Are you using an old version of TOAD? Does the package contain any conditional compilation?

Answer (score 1):

This user on the Oracle Forums seems to have had a similar issue, you could try following their solution.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=604091